# Xeon Processor or Corei7 for Mysql as a Database Server?

Tags: linux, mysql, central-processing-unit, intel, xeon

I have a wordpress database (4GB). I have two servers with the following spec:

```
       Processor          Cores    RAM       HDD       DBMS
  1.  Xeon  X5650 2.6GHz    6     64GB   250GB SSD  Mariadb 10.1
  2.  Corei7 4740 3.4GHz    4     32GB   250GB SSD  Mariadb 10.1
```

I run a query which is a LEFT JOIN on two tables (wp_posts, wp_term_relationships) on both servers and I get surprised when I see the results. I run query with and without configuring my.cnf. If I run the query on the 1st server the execution time varies from 4.48s to 5.2s and if I run the query the execution time on the 2nd one varies from 1.8s to 3.2!! I thought Xeon Processors are much faster than the Corei ones! But with these results I think I have to use one of the Corei7 CPU family for my database server which is expected to be very busy (a lot of query). If it is, why Xeon CPUs are specially designed for servers?? I wonder to know which kind of CPU the big companies with a great database load query are using?

Answer (score 0):

The Xeon series aren't necessarily faster than the Core i series, however the use case is different.

Core i

- More GHz per $$$
- On board graphics
- Overclocking

Xeon

- More L3 cache
- ECC RAM support
- Available with more cores
- Last longer under heavy load

It seems like your MariaDB profits more from a higher GHz than more cores in this case. Hope this helps you in making a suitable choice for choosing a CPU.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas. Because Mariadb and MySql uses one core for each query I should use a CPU with a higher GHz as you said. You are saying Xeon will last longer under heavy load, you mean Core i cpus cannot withstand under heavy load? I want to use caching as well, in order to make  less database connection.